# without Application class I got this error android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, casting

I have this error, when I try to do as this [link](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/). Also I didn't have Application class, must I have one at my project?

MainActivity5 java

```
 public class MainActivity5 extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity5);


        Context ctx=getApplicationContext();

          map=( (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

          map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Marker newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(arg0)
                    .title("Title")
                    .snippet("Description")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(MainActivity5.createDrawableFromView((Activity)getApplicationContext(), marker))));

            }
        });

       }

     // Convert a view to bitmap
      public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Activity context, View view) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

     }
```

manifest file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapp1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
      >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity5"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      </application>
```

I got this error when the App is lunched:

[image]

what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The method `getApplicationContext()` returns Context which is a application object - you could not cast it to Activity because the type of this object is `Application`. If you want to use `MainActivity5` you should call `MainActivity5.this`, or if you need your custom application object you have to create new class which extends `Application` class and register it in your `AndroidManifest`.

```
<application
    android:name="your.package.YourApplicationClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext()` returns an `Application` object not. You can not cast it to an `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext()` does not return an `Activity`. Simply remove the `(Activity)` cast from your `getApplicationContext()` call in your `onClick()` method.

Even better, get rid of every occurrence of `getApplicationContext()` from this code, replacing it with `this` (or, where needed, `MainActivity5.this`). **Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know *why* you are using `getApplicationContext()`**. [This blog post by Dave Smith](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) will help you determine when to use what sort of `Context`.